# C++: TypeDef using Tuples

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a typedef using tuples here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp"
using namespace std;
typedef tuple<std::string, unsigned int, double>  Person;

void Print(Person people)
{

};

int main()
{
    using boost::tuple;

    Person p0 (string("Udbhav"),10,10);
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to call the get<>() on p0 from boost when I do this. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Slava it's okay for smaller programs.

Comment: Show us where you use p0.get<0>()?

Comment: @RohanBari right, except when it produces problem that OP is having.

Comment: @Dai `boost::tuple` will not resolve without namespace. `typedef` is not a macro

Comment: No, not including any other files. I am trying to access the get<>() function in main itself. Trying to call it on Person p0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your program that you use pesky `using namespace std;` statement so your `typedef` resolves tuple as `std::tuple`. Looks like you assumed that `using boost::tuple;` in `main()` allowed you to use one from boost, which is wrong. `typedef` is not a macro and name resolution there happens at time of declaration, not using it. You can test that with removing `using namespace std;` and your `typedef` will fail to compile:

[Live example](https://ideone.com/oYHABr)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help. Made sure std would not be an issue and it worked. here is the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp"
using namespace std;
typedef  boost::tuple<string,unsigned int,double>  Person;

void Print(Person people)
{
    cout << "Name : " << people.get<0>() << endl;
    cout<< "Age : " << people.get<1>() << endl;
    cout << "Height : " << people.get<2>() << endl;
};

int main()
{
    using boost::tuple;
    Person p0("Shuniya",0,0);
    Person p1("Alpha",1,1);
    Person p2("Beta", 2, 2);
    Print(p0);
    p0.get<1>() = 1;
    Print(p0);

    return 0;
}
```